# Uncaught reference error for echo function in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

I have used the follwoing php code snippet inside a java script code(inside a parent html).

```
<script>
    function setOptions(d) {
        <?php
            echo "test";
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

When the content is saved and the web page is refreshed, I get the following error,

Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

Note- echo works when directly used inside the html code.

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is it, you think this code should do? Currently you just create a function, whose whole body consists of `test` and nothing else. This result in the error as `test` is not declared as a variable/function/... anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to happen?  When this code is parsed by PHP it sends this to the browser (not valid JavaScript in the function):

```
<script>
    function setOptions(d) {
test
    }
</script>
```

So what is produced needs to be valid JavaScript which something like this:

```
<script>
    function setOptions(d) {
        <?php
            echo 'alert("test");';
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

Would produce valid JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function setOptions(d) {
alert("test");
    }
</script>
```